# Problema al ejecutar acción de mi enrutamiento por defecto

Tags: asp.net-core

Quisiera saber porqué no se ejecuta la acción `Welcome`.

**HelloWorldController.cs**

```
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    // 
    // GET: /HelloWorld/

    public string Index(string name)
    {
        return "This is my default action...";

    }

    // 
    // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

    public string Welcome()
    {
        return "This is the Welcome action method...";
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=HelloWorldController}/{action=Welcome}/{id?}");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta mal configurado tu archivo `Startup.cs`, deberías considerar el nombre del controlador.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=HelloWorld}/{action=Welcome}/{id?}"
                );
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Enrutamiento de ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: Muchas gracias :)